# How can I catch NotFoundHttpException in laravel to send a custom response?

Tags: laravel, exception

I can't understand why laravel doesn't catch the NotFoundHttpException, but it does catch all other exceptions.

I want to send a custom json response to my users depending on the type of exception, this works for all the listed exceptions except the NotFoundHttpException:

```
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{

    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        switch (true) {
            case $exception instanceof QueryException:
                return response()->json('QueryException')

            case $exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException:
                return response()->json('NotFoundHttpException')

            case $exception instanceof AuthenticationException:
                return response()->json('AuthenticationException')

            default:
                return response()->json('Different Exception')
        }

        //return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

When I make a request to create a NotFoundHttpException, laravel responds with the default switch case option, any recommendations on this?

Comment: try instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException

Comment: @AhmedAboud, I have already tried this, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel's exception handler decides how to handle the throwing of exceptions and the ModelNotFoundException is ignored by default.

Check the file at app/Exceptions/Handler.php which will extend the exception handler in the Laravel framework.

Take a look at the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#the-exception-handler

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You are absolutely right! Laravel ignores the ModelNotFoundException, which instead renders a NotFoundHttpException, when working in a local debug environment.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to this problem, I still don't exactly understand how this works, but it worked for me, let me explain:

When I had the APP_DEBUG=true in the .env file, and was using the default render function in the Handler class, it was throwing me a 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException'.

But when I did a get_class($exception) to make sure it ws throwing the same class, for some reason it was throwing a 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException'. So I just changed my code to catch that exception:
        namespace App\Exceptions;

```
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{

    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        switch (true) {
            case $exception instanceof QueryException:
                return response()->json('QueryException')

            case $exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException:
                return response()->json('ModelNotFoundException')

            case $exception instanceof AuthenticationException:
                return response()->json('AuthenticationException')

            default:
                return response()->json('Different Exception')
        }

        //return parent::render($request, $exception); //This throws a ModelNotFoundException
    }
}
```

This solved the problem, but I'm still not understanding why it throws a different exception the default way.

This is the code that throws the exception when I send a get request to localhost:8000/api/users/$id, to a non existing user id.

```
//UserController.php

public function show(User $user)
{
    return new UserResource($user);
}
```

Comment: because the query returns nothing

Comment: are you using findOrFail() ?

Comment: @AhmedAboud, I am using route model binding, you can check the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding)